# Can I send a string (or a specific number) on connecting an Async socket

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, ipc

I would like to send a unique identifier A I connect an IPC socket.

```
IPEndPoint epServer = new IPEndPoint(aryLocalAddr[0], port);

socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Blocking = false;
socket.BeginConnect(epServer, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallBack), socket);
```

Is there any way to add something to socket, such that the Listener(Acceptor) is able to pick up this unique ID? I want to do this in the connection step.

Comment: This is something your protocol should dictate, like _"When a client connects, it generates a [UUID] and sends that to the server in a [connect] message"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are limited by the Protocol. You can only ever send something that can be sent via a set Frame.

[TCP on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)

Before Data Exchange can happen you first have to get into the "ESTABLISHED" state.
`Connect()` brings you there, so you can not send Data before you are connected because your connection was not established.

You can however connect to a server and then immediately send your first message. Your server can wait for your client's first message and, if it is not the expected message, close the connection.